# Distinct question

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two fields; firstname & lastname

I want to select Distinct lastnames but display both the first & last name in the results...for instance:

```
'SELECT DISTINCT lastname FROM people
```

will return just the lastname. How can I also display the firstname?

Comment: Even if it was possible, what purpose could such a query serve? Think about it, there isn't a single Firstname associated with the grouped Lastname...Perhaps you want to randomly select a person?

Comment: and as I point out, it's obviously not possible (as you intend)

Comment: Just select all the data, and then implement this grouping concept in the presentation layer of the app

Comment: I think you haven't thought this through thoroughly. Try doing it by hand for a few items and you will see that there is no way to meaningfully do it even on paper. For example, say you have Bob Smith and Joe Smith. What do you want that row to display, "Bob,Joe  Smith"?

Comment: I've simplified my case...In actuality it is a database of 20M records & selecting ALL of the records isn't an option due to performance issues. I therefore need to grab a subset (ie this is where the DISTINCT part comes to play) & then use a value from another column for further processing.....as I point out in a comment below, it doesn't matter if it's Bob Jones or Dave Jones that is returned...getting 1 is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL doesn't generally respond well to ambiguity. If you want to include only one instance of a last name, but any one corresponding first name, you'll have to describe how to choose which first name (even if you don't really care). Perhaps:

```
SELECT MIN(firstname), lastname
FROM ...
GROUP BY lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have this data:

```
LastName   FirstName
Jones      Bob
Jones      Dave
```

Do you want to display both "Bob Jones" and "Dave Jones"?
Then you would do:

SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, LastName FROM people

If that's not what you want, how do you determine which first name to use?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
  echo "<br />";
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Taken from:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Very simple but good tutorial and I think applies perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using MySQL, this query will work and return a "random" first name (it might always return the same for a while, then change after an update / delete / insert into query) :

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM people GROUP BY LastName
```

Please note this query **will not** work on any intelligent RDMBS (i.e. not MySQL). A good way to do this (and actually pick random first names) would be by using analytical functions (PostgreSQL syntax) :

```
WITH TT AS (
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LastName ORDER BY random()) AS R
    FROM people
)
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM TT
WHERE R = 1;
```

Unfortunately for you, MySQL doesn't know CTE and analytical functions and makes it much harder to randomize things like this.